# Intellij IDEA - IvyCache does not recognize dependencies

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ivy

- **Intellij Ultimate - 12.1**
- **JDK 1.7.0_10 (Sun/Oracle)**
- **IvyIDEA - 1.0.8**

They seem to be the latest version of the plugins/IDEs. When I import a new project from eclipse, IDEA does not recognize my libraries (Eclipse nicely detected and added these libraries to my classpath).

I added IvyIDEA as a facet and supplied the ivy.xml, ivy-settings.xml and the build.properties then did a Tools -> Resolve for all modules which prints me the following (when I enable IvyIDEA logging at info level)

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|                  |            modules            ||   artifacts   |
|       conf       | number| search|dwnlded|evicted|| number|dwnlded|
---------------------------------------------------------------------
|      runtime     |   55  |   49  |   0   |   8   ||  157  |   0   |
|    war-runtime   |   47  |   41  |   0   |   7   ||  140  |   0   |
|     build-war    |   47  |   41  |   0   |   7   ||  140  |   0   |
|    build-main    |   47  |   41  |   0   |   7   ||  140  |   0   |
| build-tests-unit |   52  |   46  |   0   |   7   ||  152  |   0   |
|build-tests-integr|   50  |   44  |   0   |   7   ||  148  |   0   |
---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

No problems detected during resolve for module

But after this nothing happens i.e, *no libraries* are added to my project. What am I missing and how do I go about debugging this?

Comment: Same issue here. In the project panel, IvyIDEA would appear under External Libraries in a project that was successfully set up, but not in this new project I tried to set up.